# Is it possible to create Crystal binds for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, crystal-lang

I'm creating a [m3u8](https://github.com/marceloboeira/m3u8.cr) generator/parser for crystal, yet I want to use it later with ruby. Is that possible/easy to do it?

Comment: Yes, you export the functions in your crystal library to C and then create a ruby wrapper for that, see https://firmhouse.com/blogwrapping-up-a-c-library-for-ruby-it-s-actually-pretty-easy/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create Ruby extension using Crystal. It's enough to [bind](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/c_bindings/) Ruby lib.
There's an interesting [presentation by Anna Kazakowa](https://www.slideshare.net/AnnaKazakova/how-to-write-ruby-extensions-with-crystal) regarding that topic.

See also:

- [phoffer/crystalized_ruby](https://github.com/phoffer/crystalized_ruby)
- [manastech/crystal_ruby](https://github.com/manastech/crystal_ruby)